# How to perform conditional mutate on unspecified columns (e.g. matching regex)?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr, levels

I have a nested data.frame - `df_nested`, there one of column contains `df`:

```
df <- tibble(ID_Value = 1:8,
             xyz001 = c("text4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "text2"), 
             xyz002 = c(NA, NA, NA, "text3", "text1", NA, NA, NA),
             xyz003 = c(NA, "text1", NA, NA, "text2", NA, "text2", NA))
```

I want to find a way, how to mutate this df, on these requirements:

1. `mutate(across(matches("\\d")`
2. there are 4 cases - 4 levels by priority. text4 <- text3 <- text2 <- text1:
   I need to find and keep column values containing only the highest level text. e.g. if column contains text4, I want to remove text3, text2, text1 and replace them to NA.
   If it contains multiple highest order text, we should keep all these values (e.g. column xyz003).
3. how to apply these conditions not specifying column name, because there can be any number in column name.
4. if column contains all NAs, do nothing.

my attempt:

```
df_nested <- df_nested %>%
    mutate(df = map(data, ~.x %>%
       mutate(across(matches("\\dd"), function (x) {
                      conditions (ifelse, case_when or other)
                      ...}
```

Also, should we better use `across()`, or is `vars()` still a good way to do it as well?
Thank you in advance.

**Expected Output**

```
df <- tibble(ID_Value = 1:8,
             xyz001 = c("text4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
             xyz002 = c(NA, NA, NA, "text3", NA, NA, NA, NA),
             xyz003 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "text2", NA, "text2", NA))
```

Comment: Why tier1 is absent in row 2 and tier2 in last row of your expected output?

Comment: i needed a solution to iterate columnwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a `factor` type to specify the order you want.
2. Do row- or column-wise operations across the matches.

Consider this function

```
max_only <- function(x, lvls) {
  fct <- droplevels(factor(x, lvls))
  `[<-`(x, as.integer(fct) != length(levels(fct)), NA_character_)
}
```

You can then specify any order you want

```
> max_only(c("apple", "banana", NA_character_), c("banana", "apple"))
[1] "apple" NA      NA     
> max_only(c("apple", "banana", NA_character_), c("apple", "banana"))
[1] NA       "banana" NA
```

---

#### Case 1: column-wise operations

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("\\d"), max_only, c("tier1", "tier2", "tier3", "tier4")))
```

Output (this one looks more like your expected output)

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ID_Value xyz001 xyz002 xyz003
     <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1        1 tier4  NA     NA    
2        2 NA     NA     NA    
3        3 NA     NA     NA    
4        4 NA     tier3  NA    
5        5 NA     NA     tier2 
6        6 NA     NA     NA    
7        7 NA     NA     tier2 
8        8 NA     NA     NA
```

---

#### Case 2: row-wise operations

```
df %>% 
  mutate(as.data.frame(t(apply(
    across(matches("\\d")), 1L, 
    max_only, c("tier1", "tier2", "tier3", "tier4")
  ))))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ID_Value xyz001 xyz002 xyz003
     <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1        1 tier4  NA     NA    
2        2 NA     NA     tier1 
3        3 NA     NA     NA    
4        4 NA     tier3  NA    
5        5 NA     NA     tier2 
6        6 NA     NA     NA    
7        7 NA     NA     tier2 
8        8 tier2  NA     NA
```

---

#### Explanations

1. `[<-` is almost equivalent to `x[...] <- y; x`. If `...` is a logical vector (i.e. TRUE/FALSE), then values in `x` indexed by TRUE will be replaced by `y`. For example,

   ```
    > x <- c("a", "b" ,"c")
    > `[<-`(x, c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), NA_character_)
    [1] "a" NA  NA 
    > x[c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)] <- NA_character_; x
    [1] "a" NA  NA
   ```
2. `NA_character_` is the NA value of a character type.
3. `as.integer(fct) != length(levels(fct))` returns a logical vector of the same length as `fct`. TRUE indexes positions where the values of `fct` are not the highest level, FALSE indexes the opposite, and NA indexes NAs. For example, assume that `fct` looks like this

   ```
    > x <- c("apple", "banana", NA)
    > fct <- droplevels(factor(x, c("apple", "banana", "pear")))
    > fct
    [1] apple  banana <NA>  
    Levels: apple banana
   ```

   Then, you can see that

   ```
    > as.integer(fct) != length(levels(fct))
    [1]  TRUE FALSE    NA
   ```
4. All together, it just means that we assign `NA_character_`s to values that are not equal to the highest level but keep NAs unchanged.

   ```
   [<-(x, as.integer(fct) != length(levels(fct)), NA_character_)
   ```

Comment: I think it may be a solution. I will get back after investigation. I wish I knew factor().
Can you explain that is here, specially this combo of symbols `[<-`? 
`[<-`(x, as.integer(fct) != length(levels(fct)), NA_character_)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowwise` with `c_across` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(col = suppressWarnings(max(c_across(matches('\\d+')), na.rm = TRUE)))

#  ID_Value xyz001 xyz002 xyz003 col  
#     <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1        1 tier4  NA     NA     tier4
#2        2 NA     NA     tier1  tier1
#3        3 NA     NA     NA     NA   
#4        4 NA     tier3  NA     tier3
#5        5 NA     tier1  tier2  tier2
#6        6 NA     NA     NA     NA   
#7        7 NA     NA     tier2  tier2
#8        8 tier2  NA     NA     tier2
```

Taking `max` on character values doesn't make sense (and generates warnings) but here we can use it to get the output directly.

---

To keep only the max value in each row we can reshape the data :

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID_Value) %>%
  group_by(ID_Value) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, -which.max(readr::parse_number(value)), NA)) %>%
  pivot_wider()

#  ID_Value xyz001 xyz002 xyz003
#     <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1        1 tier4  NA     NA    
#2        2 NA     NA     tier1 
#3        3 NA     NA     NA    
#4        4 NA     tier3  NA    
#5        5 NA     NA     tier2 
#6        6 NA     NA     NA    
#7        7 NA     NA     tier2 
#8        8 tier2  NA     NA
```

Comment: tier4,  tier3 2 and 1 can be any text. And I have added expected output.

Comment: It should work as far as the text is the same for all the columns. I have updated the answer to produce output similar to the expected output and also used `parse_number` to deal with only number instead of text.

Comment: I think the better approach would be to name somehow all four cases, as I mentioned tierX can be any text. I gave the number just to show priority.  And yes, the same 4 conditions (strings) are the same throughout columns.

Comment: If number does not denote the priority then what does? How do we know which value to keep and which to turn `NA` ?

Comment: lets say tier4 could be = "string4", tier3 = "string3". I just meant, that first we check all values containing string3, and remove the rest.

Comment: So there is still 4 and 3 in it, right? Did you try the answer , did you get any errors?

Comment: it does not work. there can be cases without number, just a plain text. also in your comment, it did not produced that i wanted. col xyz001 should have only tier4 values.